# display: hidden CSS not working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make parts of a list hidden when the page loads.

Specifically the `sdt_wrap` class of my HTML.
I know that the display:hidden is in the correct spot it just is not taking in the hidden value

Here is the CSS:

```
ul.sdt_menu li span.sdt_wrap{
    position:absolute;
    top:25px;
    left:50px;
    width:170px;
    height:150px;
    z-index:501;
    display: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Possibly being overridden by higher level CSS selectors, based on specificity. I'd check firebug to see what's overriding it, and set up a higher specificity order (#content ul.sdt_menu.... for example).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/display

Comment: Wow. 8 years ago this was asked

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`hidden` is not a valid value for `display`. You're looking for `none`, as in:

```
ul.sdt_menu li span.sdt_wrap{
    display:none;
}
```

**Documentation**

CSS `display` on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/display

Answer (score 13):

It's `display:none` or `visibility:hidden`. 'hidden' is not a valid value for 'display'.

Answer (score 0):

use `visibility:hidden`; or `opacity: 0;` property